# Uninstalling PowerShell 1.0

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell, uninstall

I am attempting to standardize our PowerShell deployment and usage across all servers, which involves uninstalling PS1.0/installing PS2.0 on Server 2003 machines. In searching for [KB926139](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926139/) through CMD and Control Panel Add/Remove Programs, it is nowhere to be found. We have [KB926141](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926141) installed on these servers as the Language Pack update, but no initial Install Update.

PowerShell 1.0 is installed on the server and can be found at the default locations (%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\V1.0, %windir%\Syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\V1.0).

I would like to avoid deleting the Registry Entry in this situation since it should be pretty simple, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ddono25,
You could use [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to execute a remove/install script against a list of hosts. Do you need help with something to remove the files?

Comment: That looks like it would be possible. I guess I am not understanding why the update is not present.

Comment: From cmd.exe execute wmic qfe list full |findstr "KB926139" or wmic qfe list full /format:htable > c:\tmp\output.html to print the whole list of KB's installed to a nice pretty HTML table.

Comment: My comment got a bit messy there; if you run that string then it should tell you if the KB is installed, and the details along with it.